# C#, Finding system's default method's body

Tags: c#

I just started coding with C# and wondered why there is no body in system-defined classes. for example when you look inside the class System.object the methods like ToString() have no body, see the picture below.
[Class system.Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryBvZ.png)

This is where not the class object nor the method ToString is abstract.

Comment: You are looking at the exposed functionality (probably derived from the compiled assembly), not at the actual source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system source code is not available, instead, it has been compiled to byte code. Therefore, since the source code is not available, only definitions are displayed when browsing it in Visual Studio. If you want to see the source code for the .NET library, you can take a look at the [reference source](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Object.cs,d9262ceecc1719ab).

Comment: https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Object.cs,d9262ceecc1719ab for Net code not just old Net Framework code.

Comment: @Ralf My bad, too bad Google shows it as first search result... Edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're viewing only the metadata of `Object` class. Here you can check only available fields and methods of this class.

If you check [`System.Object.ToString()`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Object.cs,ff31a6bf27c58f89,references) method in a .NET source browser, you can see that `ToString()` method has its own definition – by default it's name of the class, as comment says.

Answer (score 0):

As [Wexos mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74852784/712649), the system libraries contain *byte code* (or IL - Intermediate Language code).

You can use reflection to obtain the compiled IL instructions associated with a given method:

```
var objectClass = typeof(object);
var actualInstructions = objectClass.GetMethod("GetHashCode")
                                    .GetMethodBody()
                                    .GetILAsByteArray();
```

Now all you need to do is parse the [IL instructions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CIL_instructions) :)